# How do you prove that $x|x|$ is differentiable at all points?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

In general how do you prove that if two functions are not differentiable at a point, then it is not necessary that their product is not differentiable at that point. (Which in $x|x|$ is $0$ )

Comment: To prove your general statement, just use the example you just gave! Proof by counter example is legitimate.

Comment: You can study the cases $x<0$, $x=0$, and $x>0$ separately. For $x<0$, then $x|x|=-x^2$, which is differentiable. For $x>0$, then $x|x|=x^2$ which is differentiable. For $x=0$ you prove it directly from the definition $(x|x|)'|_{x=0}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x|x|-0|0|}{x}=\lim_{h\to0}|x|=0$. Since the limit exists, the derivative exits.

Comment: Is x=0 the only point of probable discontinuity? I mean to ask, are the probable points of discontinuity of a product function only those points  of discontinuity of the individual functions or is it possible to have other points of discontinuity as well?

Comment: If you have more to ask about this topic, it is best to start up a new question, rather than to ask in a comment where no-one will notice it.

Comment: @Seylin Yes, since the product of two continuous functions at a point is continuous at that same point, then the failure of continuity can only occur at points where at least one of the factors is not continuous. Likewise, for differentiability.

Comment: Please note that although you accepted my answer, it is inadequate for the reasons stated in the comments below it. However, since you accepted the answer, I cannot delete it. You should un-accept my answer and accept @ncmathsadist's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, of course, we can find the derivative.

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dx}x|x|&=&|x|\frac{dx}{dx}+x\frac{d|x|}{dx}\\
&=&|x|+x\cdot\frac{|x|}{x}\\
&=&|x|\left(1+\frac{x}{x}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
which is undefined at $x=0$ but which has limit $0$ at $x=0$. Since the function is continuous at $x=0$ and has a horizontal tangent at $x=0$ it is the case that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}x|x|=2|x| $$
for all $x$.

ADDENDUM: Here is a complete proof that $\frac{d}{dx}(x|x|)=2|x|$ using the definition
$$ f^\prime(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$

\begin{eqnarray}
f^\prime(x)&=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)|x+h|-x|x|}{h}\cdot{\color{blue}{\frac{(x+h)|x+h|+x|x|}{(x+h)|x+h|+x|x|}}}\\
&=&\text{a few omitted algebra steps}\\
&=&\lim_{h\to0}\frac{4(x+h)^3+6(x+h)^2h+4(x+h)h+2+h^3}{(x+h)|x+h|+x|x|}\\
&=&\frac{4x^3}{2x|x|}\\
&=&2|x|
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: "which has limit $2\lvert x\rvert$ at $x=0$" doesn't mean anything. Once you have taken the limit as $x\to 0$, there is no meaning for the symbol $x$.

Comment: Why do you not just write "which has limit $0$ at $x=0$" instead of going (now) to "limiting functions" (which has no sandard meaning, unless you are talking about asymptotic equivalence, in which case this is (1) overkill and (2) requiring to be specified)?

Comment: @ClementC. Well, the point is that the function $y=2|x|$ is, in fact, the derivative of the function $y=x|x|$, including at $x=0$. I will amend my answer to make that explicit.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales The issue with the limit is clear what you mean. I would say that it is practically an irrelevant concern. However, there is an omitted argument in the proof, which is significantly more advanced that any of the parts said explicitly. This is, the argument of why the existence of the limit of the derivative, plus continuity of the function, implies the existence of the derivative at the point. None of what is currently written ensures that the derivative exists at $x=0$. Hint: You will need to use, L'Hospital, or Mean Value Theorem, or prove it from scratch.

Comment: This is mostly unnecessary. It's clear that $f(x)= x^2$ for $x>0,$ $ f(x)= -x^2$ for $x<0.$ Hence $f$ is differentiable everywhere in $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}.$ The only thing left to check is whether $f'(0)$ exists, which is covered in the answer of @ncmathsadist.

Comment: @zhw I agree but since OP accepted the answer, MSE will not let me delete it.

Answer (score 12):

You only need to check at $x = 0$ in which case
$$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0}{h|h|\over h} = \lim_{h\to 0} |h| = 0.$$
The rest is clear.